# bigcommerce single page checkout not working in checkout sdk

Tags: bigcommerce

hello every one i am new in big commerce.
Now i am updating single page checkout using checkout sdk. every thing work fine till now i am following git hub implementing instructions . But the the problem is  after update customer shipping address need to select the shipping option for shipping. I am using this syntax for doing this

```
const saddress = {
                address1: $('#shippingaddress').val(),
                address2: "",
                city: $('#shippingcity').val(),
                company: "",
                country: $('#shippingcountry').val(),
                countryCode: "AU",
                customFields: [],
                email: $('#email').val(),
                firstName: $('#shippingfname').val(),
                lastName:$('#shippinglname').val(),
                phone: $('#shippingphone').val(),
                postalCode: $('#shippingzip').val(),
                stateOrProvince: $('#shippingProvince').val(),
                stateOrProvinceCode:  $('#shippingProvince').val(),
            };
             const updateaddress = await 
            service.updateShippingAddress(saddress);
```

After complete this action the function return all shipping address details along with the ID column and  shipping options available in this address. but the problem is that function return the options and also  the shipping  address details but no ID column found in  that list. that's why i am sending the billing address ID for select shipping option this is my code

```
 const newState = await service.selectShippingOption(billing_ID, Shippingoption_ID);
```

after that i am going to direct payment options my code is

```
      const payment = await service.loadPaymentMethods();
      let paymentmethod=payment.data.getPaymentMethods();
```

in this function i am getting all the payment options details then i go for payment  my code is

```
wait service.initializePayment({ methodId: 'testgateway' });

            const payment = {
                methodId: 'testgateway',
                paymentData: {
                    ccExpiry: { month: 10, year: 20 },
                    ccName: 'BigCommerce',
                    ccNumber: '4111111111111111',
                    ccType: 'visa',
                    ccCvv: 123,
                },
            };
```

After complete this function this function return a error

```
Error: "Your order is missing a shipping method. Please return to the 
shopping cart and checkout again."
```

Comment: It sounds like you are not getting the shipping option id back after creating the initial shipment. I don't see anything in your code above where you get the shipping option. https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js#set-shipping-details

Comment: yes, now it's work